# Windows 8.1 how to disable certain programs when pc is connected to certain networks?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1

I use my laptop in different environments. Most of the time I'm connected with unlimited wifi or ethernet, often I'm connected through tethering cellular 3G. Since I run Dropbox Bittorrent Sync and other programs that potentially could use a lot of bandwidth (that I don't have on my mobile contract) I was wondering if there's a way, a script a program that can recognize the network and enable / disable certain applications.

Comment: The trivial but limited solution is to mark networks as private/public and configure the firewall to block the problematic programs on public networks.

Comment: I can try this, but if there could be a simple app / script that can manage this will be much better.